# Symfony не работает post

Tags: symfony

Добрый день. Есть `MainController.php` контролер, в котором функция

```
/**
* @Route("/main", name="main")
*/
public function showAction()
{
    //Получение $records
    return $this->render("main.html.twig",array("record"=>$records));
}
```

Дальше есть шаблон `main.html.twig` в котором из переданных данных строится страница:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method='post'>
        <!--//Построение страницы-->
        <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
        <input type='submit' value='delete'>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Не знаю, как принять запрос от этой формы внутри контроллера. Я написал функцию, думал может она что поймает

```
public function requestAction(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->request->get('delete');
}
```

Но он даже сюда не попадает, даже не делаю возврата `Response` или `render`, если их нет и в функцию попадает, то ошибку должен выкидывать,а он ничего не выкидывает и не выводит - значит не попадает. Вопрос, наверное, простой и глупый, но может есть симфонисты, которые не пройдут мимо и подскажут как поймать запрос с формы с шаблона в контроллере)

Comment: а куда у вас запрос то отправляется? на какой url стучится?

Comment: Да я уже разобрался, запрос можно получить из функции в которой render на шаблон делается, т.е в данном случае из  showAction(), просто из $_POST все достать.

Comment: не надо из $_POST доставать, это Symfony, тут есть объект $request, из которого вы сможете все достать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Запрос можно получить из функции контроллера в которой render на шаблон делается, т.е в данном случае из showAction, просто используем `if(isset($_POST['delete']))` и делаем все, что нужно